# How to remove the nested loop join for large tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, nested-loops, database-performance

There are 3 tables in SQL Server with large amount of data, each table contains about `100000` rows. There is one SQL to fetch rows from the three tables. Its performance is very bad.

```
WITH t1 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        LeadId, dbo.get_item_id(Log) AS ItemId, DateCreated AS PriceDate
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
             t.ID, t.LeadID, t.Log, t.DateCreated, f.AskingPrice
         FROM 
             t
         JOIN 
             f ON f.PKID = t.LeadID
         WHERE 
             t.Log LIKE '%xxx%') temp
)
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM t1
JOIN s ON s.ItemID = t1.ItemId
```

When checking its estimated execution plan, I find it uses a nested loop join with large rows. Loot at the screenshot below. The top part in the image return 124277 rows, and the bottom part is executed 124277 times! I guess this is why it is so slow.

[image]

[image]

We know that nested loop has big performance issue with large data. How to remove it, and use hash join or other join instead?

Edit: Below is the related function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[get_item_Id](@message VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS VARCHAR(200) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result VARCHAR(200),
            @index int

    --Sold in eBay (372827580038).
    SELECT @index = PatIndex('%([0-9]%)%', @message)
    IF(@index = 0)
     SELECT @result='';
    ELSE 
     SELECT @result= REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@message, PatIndex('%([0-9]%)%', @message),8000), '.', ''),'(',''),')','')
    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @result
END;
```

Comment: Can you paste the whole execution plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ so we can see the whole thing, too? Also, please share the **table structures** involved, and any indices that are present on your tables

Comment: Using a function will force it to go RBAR.  That's the  first thing I would look into.

Comment: What is the warning on the nested loops operator? I would expect that to indicate a `CROSS JOIN` but that doesn't seem evident in the code you posted

Comment: @MartinSmith. Thanks very much. I will try to apply your code. In my original post, do you know why it uses nested loop join? I guess this is the biggest time consuming place.

Comment: post the execution plan as requested in the initial comment by @marc_s. I'm not sure what that warning icon is about. Also do you still get it with the inline TVF in use?

Comment: could you try with a query hint…option(NO_PERFORMANCE_SPOOL)

Comment: @MartinSmith. Here is the execution plan on brentozar.com. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkBrjsKiY  I really want to know why it is nested loop join.

Comment: Perhaps this is due to outdated statistics for atblTransaction table.

Comment: @AntonGrig - Nope. Even by its own estimates it is going to end up blowing the row count up to 11 billion rows and produce a plan with a cost of `55,302` so this isn't the case that it thinks the plan will be cheap due to bad estimates, it just generates a hideously inefficient plan, presumably due to the non schema bound UDF being used in the join condition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason it has decided to do `s cross join t1` then evaluate the function (result aliased as Expr1002) and then do a filter on [s].[ItemID]=[Expr1002] (instead of doing an equi join).

It estimates that it will have `88,969` and `124,277` rows going into the cross join (which means it would produce `11,056,800,413`)

Executing the scalar UDF after the cross join an estimated 11 billion times and then filtering the estimated 11 billion rows down does seem crazy. If it was evaluated before the join it would be evaluated much fewer times and would also be an equi join so could also use `HASH` or `MERGE` inner joins and just read all tables once without blowing the row count up.

I reproduced this locally and the behaviour changed when the UDF was created `WITH SCHEMABINDING` - SQL Server will then see that it does not access any tables and that it is deterministic in its definition.

Trace flag `8606` output appears to support this being the issue.
In both cases the "Simplified Tree" stage represents the query as a cross join with the predicate on the ScalarUdf. The scalar UDF is annotated "IsDet" or "IsNonDet" dependant on whether or not the function is schema bound. In the former case the "Project Normalization" stage pushes the calculation back up before the join and gives it an alias referenced in the join itself, in the non deterministic case this does not happen.

I strongly suggest getting rid of this scalar function and replacing it with an inline version though as non inline scalar functions have many well known additional performance problems apart from this.

The new function would be

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_item_Id_inline (@message VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN
      (SELECT item_Id = CASE
                          WHEN PatIndex('%([0-9]%)%', @message) = 0 THEN ''
                          ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@message, PatIndex('%([0-9]%)%', @message), 8000), '.', ''), '(', ''), ')', '')
                        END)
```

and rewritten query

```
WITH t1
     AS (SELECT t.LeadID,
                i.item_Id     AS ItemId,
                t.DateCreated AS PriceDate
         FROM   t
                CROSS apply dbo.get_item_Id_inline(t.Log) i
                JOIN f
                  ON f.PKID = t.LeadID
         WHERE  t.Log LIKE '%xxx%')
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM   t1
       JOIN s
         ON s.ItemID = t1.ItemId
```

there may still be room for some additional optimisations but this will be orders of magnitudes better than your current execution plan (as that is catastrophically bad).

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. It is a lot help!

Answer (score 0):

To optimize the query, do the following:

1. Take the "t.Log LIKE condition '% xxx%'" to a more internal selection. This allows fewer records to be included in the join.
2. Do not use "likes".
3. Remove the top selection in your view.
4. Optimize the "dbo.get_item_id" function or use alternative solutions because
   comparisons within this function are also very time consuming.

Finally, your query will look like the following code:

```
WITH t1 AS
(
     SELECT 
          u.ID
        , u.LeadID as LeadId
        , dbo.get_item_id(u.Log) AS ItemId
        , u.DateCreated AS PriceDate
        , f.AskingPrice
    FROM 
    (select ID, LeadID, Log, DateCreated from t WHERE Log LIKE '%xxx%')u
    JOIN 
        f ON f.PKID = u.LeadID       
)
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM t1
JOIN s ON s.ItemID = t1.ItemId'
```

Comment: Thanks. I will look your suggestions and update it. In my original post, do you know why it uses nested loop?

Comment: This is determined by the query optimizer.
Different behaviors are performed when table data is ordered or indexed.
When the index is on your table then the number of comparative records in the table seems less and nested loop is selected.
You can also use query hints for Join types, but this is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

"COUNT" over a big result is never a good idea. Additionally you have `LIKE '%xxx%'`, which always results into a full scan and cannot be predicted by the optimization engine.

It know, it is a costly way, but I would redesign the application. Maybe adding some trigger and de-normalizing the data structure could be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

In case you'd still want to use the get_item_Id UDF.
Here's a golf-coded deterministic version of it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[get_item_Id](@message VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @str VARCHAR(20);
    SET @str = SUBSTRING(@message, PATINDEX('%([0-9]%',@message)+1, 20);
    IF @str NOT LIKE '[0-9]%[0-9])%' RETURN NULL;
    RETURN LEFT(@str, PATINDEX('%[0-9])%', @str));
END;
```